# cant remove underline from <p>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried many solutions to remove the text-decoration from p but without any progress.

The HTML looks like this

```html
<div class="container-fluid my-container align-items-center">
  <div class="row my-row">
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 ">
      <div class="thumbnail  d-flex justify-content-center imagePreview">
        <a href="#############" target="_blank">
          <img src="../assets/img/thumbnails/Apelles_230x177cm_2020__.jpg" alt="" style="width:400px;">
          <div class="caption">

            <!--########### Here is the p-->
            <p id="captionStyle">Apelles<br>2020</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
```

Comment: you need to style the link (anchor tag) - by default browsers will underline content inside anchors

Answer (score 4):

Browsers automatically add underscores to links for accessibility. To clear it, you can use reset.css or write this snippet:

```
a { text-decoration: none }
```

P.S. You can search CSS Reset, Normalize, and browser styles for more information.

Comment: Live sample [link](https://codepen.io/phyesix/pen/dydvvNw)